# Implementing an uiview subclass with children views using autolayout programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

My need is very generic, I have to implement an UIView subclass which groups an UIImageView, x-centered on the screen and distant 20 pts from top, and a UILabel with a description.
I have no problems doing it with interface builder, but since I needed to make it programmatically I looked after techniques and best practices. 
So far I came up with this code, starting to visualize just the image. Despite it is very basic, I am not able to understand why the view isn't deriving (as you can see from the screenshot) the proper frame which should be "offsetted" 20 points on all edges from the image view.

Here's my subclass:

**header**

```
@interface ProgrammaticAutolayoutView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;

@end
```

**implementation**

```
#import "ProgrammaticAutolayoutView.h"

@implementation ProgrammaticAutolayoutView{

    BOOL _didUpdateConstraints;
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    return [self initWithFrame:CGRectZero];;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        _didUpdateConstraints = NO;

        _imageView = [UIImageView new];
        [_imageView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: NO];

        [self addSubview: _imageView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) updateConstraints{

    if(!_didUpdateConstraints){
        [self setupConstraints];
    }

    [super updateConstraints];
}

- (void) setupConstraints{

    [self.imageView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:50]];

    [self.imageView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:50]];

    [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self.imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:20.0]];

    [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self.imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:20.0]];

    [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self.imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:20.0]];

    [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self.imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:20.0]];

    _didUpdateConstraints = YES;
}

@end
```

and this is the snippet of code I use to instantiate and draw this uiview subclass:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ProgrammaticAutolayoutView *test = [[ProgrammaticAutolayoutView alloc] init];
    [test setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    test.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dmy"];
    test.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [self.view addSubview: test];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: test attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: test attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];

    [test setNeedsLayout];
    [test layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

I was expecting to see the subview with an offset of 20 points from all edges of the uiimageview, but the result is completely different, I have no debugger logs or inconsistencies whatsoever, clearly I must be missing something very basic, but so far I didn't understand what.

[image: wrong offset on image view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constants describe X and Y offsets.  Your 4 constraints say:

- Place the top of the imageView 20 points below (+Y 20) the red View
- Place the bottom of the imageView 20 points below (+Y 20) the red View
- Place the leading edge of the imageView 20 points to the right (+X 20) of the red View
- Place the trailing edge of the imageView 20 points to the right (+X 20) of the red View

That is what your picture shows.

To make the red box frame the image you can make two of your constants negative:

```
[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self.imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:20.0]];

[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self.imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:-20.0]];

[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self.imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:20.0]];

[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self.imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:-20.0]];
```

**or** switch the order of the items in the bottom and trailing constraints:

```
[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self.imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:20.0]];

[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:20.0]];

[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self.imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:20.0]];

[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:20.0]];
```

---

The new suggested constraints say:

- Place the bottom of the imageView 20 points above (-Y 20) the red View
- Place the trailing edge of the imageView 20 points to the left (-X 20) of the red View

**or**

- Place the bottom of the red View 20 points below (+Y 20) the imageView
- Place the trailing edge of the red View 20 points to the right (+X 20) of the imageView

Comment: negative values...as obvious as that? Thank you for your answer, it was so obvious but not immediately evident to me!

Comment: You're welcome.  Interface Builder frequently switches the order of the items (which is subtle). That is why you don't often see negative values in IB.  They have the same effect of course.